# What are the differences in sentence meaning caused by the placement of 'not' in these two sentences?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, american-english

I'm translating a sentence of character dialogue from Japanese to English, and came up with two possible translations for the final sentence of the dialogue. Below is the translated dialogue.

> "His ability to speak his native language for instance, is because it’s what he may see and understand. Even so for him, when regarding himself he doesn't comprehend in the slightest. **Not his name, his family, his friends… he lacks the ability to remember any one of them**."

The last line (名前も、　家族も、　友人も…… 何ひとつ思い出せません。) can be translated as either

> His name, his family, his friends… he lacks the ability to remember **not** one of them.

or as shown above in bold

> **Not** his name, his family, his friends… he lacks the ability to remember any one of them.

What are the differences in sentence meaning caused by the different placement of 'not' in the above two sentences?

Comment: In the first translation, _lacks_, a negative, precedes and commands _not_, another negative. That's one negative too many in the clause. In the second translation, the _not_ is in the first part, and the _lacks_ is separate from it, so they reinforce one another the way they do in Chinese. But [English negation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf) is very complex.

Comment: "He lacks the ability to remember not one of them" doesn't make sense, it is confusing but equivalent to "he lacks the ability to forget them all". I'd say "he lacks the ability to remember any of them".

Comment: I would use a colon rather than ellipses. *Apples and oranges: he won't eat either.* As for the actual sentence, replace *not* with *even*. *His name, his family, his friends: he lacks the ability to remember **even** one of them.*

Comment: @nnnnnn But, I would be comfortable saying "I prepared for the quiz on Italian Presidents, but now that you give me the list of names, I can remember not one of them." Perhaps your objection is to the double negative?

Comment: @djs - "I can remember not one of them" is fine. I don't object to double negatives in a general sense, but talking about an ability to remember not one just sounds strange.